# Stripe Request failed: payment required(402)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, stripe-payments

I keep getting the above error when testing my server and i cant see  why. I succesfully created a managed account previously then when i want to add an external account with:

```
post '/account/external_account' do
  begin
    account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(params[:stripe_account])
    account.external_accounts.create(
      :object => "bank_account",
      :country => "US",
      :currency => "usd",
      :routing_number => "110000000",
      :account_number => "000123456789"
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return "Error adding external account to customer account: #{e.message}"
  end
  status 200
  return account.to_json
end
```

The stripe account id being the id of the managed account e.g  acct_19clyeKuASmJkC0m.

I get the same error when trying to save an uploaded verification id(using stripes success.png image). When using the following code to upload:

```
post '/account/id' do
  begin
    path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    image = Image.new(file: params[:file])
    image.save
    file = Stripe::FileUpload.create(
      {
        :purpose => params[:purpose],
        :file => File.new("#{path}#{image.file.url}")
      },
      {
        :stripe_account => params[:stripe_account]
      }
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return "Error saving verification id to account: #{e.message}"
  end
  status 200
  return file.to_json
end
```

I get a file id returned but then when trying to save it with the same account id using the following code:

```
post '/account/id' do
  account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(params[:stripe_account])
  account.legal_entity.verification.document = params[:file_id]
  account.save
  return account.to_json
end
```

I get the same 402 error and im not sure why. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the correct syntax for adding external accounts in the API reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#account_create_bank_account.

Basically, you're missing the `external_account` parameter name. Here is the correct syntax:

```
account.external_accounts.create(:external_account => {
  :object => "bank_account",
  :country => "US",
  :currency => "usd",
  :routing_number => "110000000",
  :account_number => "000123456789"
})
```